# Rounding a division in a specific way in Python

Tags: python, math, calculator, division

How do I round to the thousands a division in a specific way that the top persons pay more?

The division should result in the exact total amount.

I tried this:

```
total = 245000
print(round(total / 3)
```

Expected: Person1 = 82000 Person2 = 82000 Person3 = 81000

Comment: It's unclear what logic you follow to determine that person1 and person2 pay the same but person3 pays less, and it's unclear how you calculate how much less should person3 pay. Are you rounding to the thousands?

Comment: yes, rounding to the thousands.

Sorry for not explained that.

Comment: Your first two sentences seem to be a contradiction. If the amounts should be exactly the same, how could some people pay more?

Comment: In any event, `divmod(245,3) = (81,2)` which tells you that `245 = 82 + 82 + 81`

Comment: Hi Coleman, sorry for to no be clear. I edited the post. See if you get now. Many thanks

Comment: Divide `245000` by 3 and round up to the nearest 1000. Assign that to `Person1` and `Person2`, then assign the remainder to `Person3`.

Comment: how do I do that @Barmar?

Comment: Is the total amount always a multiple of 1000? If not, the stipulation that the output should be rounded to the nearest 1000 and the stipulation that it should add to the total exactly are in tension with each other.

Comment: @JohnColeman.
Yes, it always be a multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Divide `total` by 3 and round up to the next multiple of 1000. Use that for `person1` and `person2`, then subtract those from `total` to give `person3` the remainder.

```
person1 = person2 = 1000 * ceil(total / 3000)
person3 = total - person1 - person2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of people.

```py
from math import floor

def rounddown(number, ndigits):
    return 10**-ndigits * floor(number/10**-ndigits)

total = 245000
people = 3

amounts = [rounddown(total/people, -3) + i \
    for i in [1000] * int(total/1000%people) + [0] * (people-int(total/1000%people))]
```

Comment: Dennis, not sure if I follow it. But I wanna build a code that any total amount I input, it outputs a division rounded to the thousands with the top persons paying more. PS: There will always have 3 persons.

Comment: @Carlos: What part are you having difficulty understanding? This is not.a complete program. You will need to provide a way to set the values you want (using `input()`?) and a way to use the results. What I provided produces a list of the values that add up to the total. How you use those values is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that divides the amount by 1000, uses `divmod` to get the quotient and remainder when dividing the resulting amount by the number of people, then assembles a list where everyone owes 1000 times the quotient. The remainder is used to bump up some of the amounts by 1000:

```
def divide_amount(amount,num_people):
    amount //= 1000
    q,r = divmod(amount,num_people)
    bills = [1000*q for _ in range(num_people)]
    for i in range(r):
        bills[i] += 1000
    return bills

print(divide_amount(245000,3)) #[82000, 82000, 81000]
```

Comment: It is almost perfect. Which line of code do I add to input any total amount and uses it?

Comment: `int(input(...` is the standard way of getting an integer input. You can call the function if you want to use it.